# New javascript HTML element doesn't follows css rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue when i'm trying to add rows in a table using Javascript and jQuery.

My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   for (i=0; i<myvar.length; i++){
      $("#items").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"></td></tr>');
    }
});
</script>
```

My problem is that the new row did not take the style of my CSS file. CSS file loaded in `<head>`.

Did i miss something?

Comment: Make a fiddle please

Comment: what is items element?

Comment: if `#items` is the table, then you should use `$("#items").append`, not `.after` to add the elements to the table, not next to it.

Comment: @pawel the append is the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.append` instead of `.after` because `.after` is adding `tr` outside of the table that's why the CSS is not applying:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
      $("#items").append('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: @Wowsk and Dhara_Parmar this is the correct answer. I'm feeling fool right now because i did not check it before. Thanks!